# Монтируемый volume static перекрывает файлы, которые лежат в одноимённой папке

Tags: docker, docker-compose, развертывание

У меня в папке static лежит файл redoc.yaml, когда происходит авто-деплой на сервере, в контейнере монтируется volume static и туда нормально собирается статика от Django, но redoc.yaml там нет. Как правильно в данном случае поступить? Самое интересное что локально при подключении, такого не происходит, может есть какая-то настройка у докера, которая за это отвечает?

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  web:
    image: sgfat/api_yamdb:v1.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_value:/app/static/
      - media_value:/app/media/
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static_value:/var/html/static/
      - media_value:/var/html/media/
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_value:
  media_value:
```

Answer (score -1):

Интересно конечно кто минус поставил вопросу и что ему было непонятно, в любом случае сам нашёл решение. Проблема заключалась в параметре `nocopy`, дословный перевод из документации "флаг для отключения копирования данных из контейнера при создании тома" и судя по всему при локальном развёртывании он у меня имеет значение `false`, а при удалённом почему-то `true`, соответственно файлы из уже существующей папки `static` не копировались в монтируемый том. Для принудительного изменения параметра нужно использовать длинный синтаксис:

```
      - type: volume
        source: static_value
        target: /app/static
        volume:
          nocopy: false
```